# How to get entity from the argument and create if condition in Dialogflow Inline editor for fulfilment

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am completely new to Dialogflow and nodejs. I need to get the entity value from the argument to the function (agent) and apply if the condition on that. How can I achieve this?
I am trying below but every time I get else condition become true.
I have created an entity named about_member.

```
function about_member_handeller(agent)
{
    if(agent.about_member=="Tarun")
    {
    agent.add('Yes Tarun');
    }
    else
    {
        agent.add("No tarun");
    }

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you may use console.log to help unleash your black box, like below:

```
function about_member_handeller(agent) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(agent, null, 2));

     if(agent.about_member=="Tarun") {
        agent.add('Yes Tarun');
     }
     else {
        agent.add("No tarun");
     }

}
```

`JSON.stringfy()` will serialize your json object into string and console.log will print the same on the stdOut. So once you run your code this will print the object structure for `agent` and after which you will know on how to access `about_member`. Because in the above code it's obvious that you are expecting `about_member` to be a string, but this code will let you know on the actual data in it and how to compare it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the parameter you can use the following;

```
const valueOfParam = agent.parameters["parameterName"];
```